# Need a workaround when using MongoDB SQL Connector in Flink

Tags: mongodb, collections, insert, apache-flink, upsert

In our project, we have a requirement that uses Apache Flink and writes data from Flink using MongoDB SQL Connector.

According to the [Flink documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/mongodb/), the Mongo connector uses upsert semantics when inserting documents inside Mongo if primary key is not defined in DDL.

When we tried this inside a Flink table without primary key, we got this exception:

> org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Table sink 'default_catalog.default_database.Correlation' doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Join(joinType=[InnerJoin], where=[($f3 = id)], select=[graph, $f3, id, type, startDate, hascontextEntityId, providedBy, harvestedDate], leftInputSpec=[NoUniqueKey], rightInputSpec=[NoUniqueKey]) at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram$SatisfyModifyKindSetTraitVisitor.createNewNode(FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram.scala:405) at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram$SatisfyModifyKindSetTraitVisitor.visit(FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram.scala:277) at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram$SatisfyModifyKindSetTraitVisitor.visitChild(FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram.scala:366) at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram$SatisfyModifyKindSetTraitVisitor.$anonfun$visitChildren$1(FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram.scala:355) at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram$SatisfyModifyKindSetTraitVisitor.$anonfun$visitChildren$1$adapted(FlinkChangelogModeInferenceProgram.scala:354) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233) at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:155) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226) at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)

Is there any way to skip the upsert semantics and perform a plain insert inside Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

The result of your query is a changelog stream, not an append-only stream. Given that you have removed the primary key from your sink definition, it's trying to send the changelog stream to your append-only sink, but that's incompatible. So you'll need to fix your query in such a way that it results in an append-only stream and not a changelog stream.